# Is it possible to create a war from a intellij project saved as a zip

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

So basically I've been told to deploy on tomcat 6 a project someone else has done, and instead of giving me a war file he has saved the whole project as a zip (I guess he exported it) and pretends me to run it on tomcat.

So I was wondering if it's possible to do so, creating a war or some other way, even if it's not the correct way of doing it, or there isn't.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If IntelliJ project saved as zip is very important and a lot of developers want to use it but they can't, in theory it could start a war :P

Comment: sorry but, what could start a war?? Or you are telling me that people would like it, but it can't be done?

Comment: WAR = **W**eb **AR**chive , war = opposite of peace... just for clearness :-))

Comment: I created a ZIP archive for a java console application (via **maven**). Therefor I used the maven-assembly-plugin and created a special assembly descriptor. But I'm not sure if you can put a WAR file (is it OK, @JaroslawPawlak ;-) ? ) into a ZIP

Comment: @Ulrich If we could put a war inside a zip file and then delete it, it would be nice :P Or ideally all wars :P